# Looking for a better formula to rank user activity in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to create a table with every single date from `2011` - today and with every single user login_id and then the user's last activity prior to "the_date".. i.e. if this person's last activity was on `1/2/13`

```
the_date | login_id | days_since_last_activity
1/2/13        1             0
1/3/13        2             1
1/4/13        3             2
```

I'm currently using a `ROW_NUMBER` formula to rank all of the user's activity based on the date and then pulls `RANK = 1` for each the_date and does a `DATEDIFF` calculation for column `3`... each time and it's making things very inefficient (as you can imagine).

Is there any other formula that may serve the same purpose?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using an internal database within my company.

Comment: Waka Waka! No serioulsy what database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, ProstGres, ORACLE??

Comment: BOOYAH!!! Me too!!! TWINSIES!!! @user2770412

Comment: Haha. it's been a long day -- SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a table `logins` that has all the users and all the dates (although not necessarily all the combinations).  I am also using SQL Server syntax, because that has both `datediff` and window functions.

The following uses the `from` clause to get all combinations of dates and users.  It then uses a correlated subquery to get the most recent activity date prior to a given date:

```
select d.the_date, l.login_id,
       datediff(day,
                (select max(the_date)
                 from logins l2
                 where l2.login_id = l.login_id and
                       l2.the_date <= l.the_date
                ), the_date
               ) as days_since_last_activity
from (select distinct the_date from logins) d cross join
     (select distinct login_id from logins) l
where d.the_date >= '2011-01-01';
```

Comment: That is sort of in the right direction. I have one table [all_days] and one [logins] that has the login_id and all of their activities with event times. So, I need to join from Logins to All_Days and have it pull the most recent activity prior to each day in All_Days (which literally just has every day ever). I did try to adapt your solution but received an error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."